# 2d classification/recognition using a neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have 100 classified datapoints, that are a 1000x1000 grid, and the name of the grid. 10 distinct points for 10 names.

It looks like this: (in excel)

[image]

Every datapoint has between 500 to 900 points to use on the graph.

I tried classifying them using an ANN, where the network gets 256 inputs and 10 outputs.

The inputs are created using first finding the center of gravity in the graph (center is a good reference point for my case, because I have rotation and translation to worry about). I then take distances from the 256 points closest to the center, and send them to the ann.

Results are terrible..

I was wondering what method should I use, because this is not going anywhere doing like this.

Here is another image of the same name:[image]

Comment: Hard to work on this as there is no code and more important: the plots do not show any x->y mapping (e.g. coloring the points in regards to the class to predict). **Edit:** it seems that these plots show the points of one specific class to predict. But even then, there is no info about that mapping.

Comment: This question, with much more detail, might be better received on a sister site https://stats.stackexchange.com/.